# WebdavResource propfindMethod returns 404 only on depth > 1

Tags: java, tomcat6, webdav, slide

I recently inherited a Tomcat application built to browse a Webdav file structure. At one point, the app requests the root of the directory tree (/slide/files/) to build a visual directory tree.
To do this, the propfindMethod() of a WebdavResource-object is called. When I call the method with a depth of 1, I get status 207 and a list of the 1st level files. But when I go over 1 or use DepthSupport.DEPTH_INFINITY, all I get is status 404.

If further information on any aspect of this problem is needed, just ask, because I'm not even really sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "over 1" in WebDAV PROPFIND, just 0, 1, or infinity.

That being said, some servers are known not to support depth infinity for performance reasons (but in that case, you shouldn't get a 404).

Do you have an HTTP trace?